# Why did Neo go to meet the Oracle?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), after impressing Seraph, Neo meet Oracle, who leads him, ultimately, to the Architect.

Why did Neo intentionally go to meet the Oracle in this scene?

The movie [plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_Reloaded#Plot) in wikipedia doesn't specify the *reasons* behind Neo's actions:

> The Nebuchadnezzar leaves Zion and enters the Matrix, where **Neo meets the
> Oracle's bodyguard Seraph, who leads him to her**.

Comment: Because he needs to ask her where to go next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morpheus, in an earlier scene, stated that he (and Neo) believe that the Oracle needs to be consulted before the prophecy can be fulfilled.

> **Morpheus:** *I must ask one of you for help. Some of you believe as I believe. Some of you do not. But those of you that do, know we are nearing the end of our struggle. The prophecy will be fulfilled soon, but **before it can be, the Oracle must be consulted.***

They recognise that they're heading toward some kind of accelerating end-game with the rapid release of new minds into Zion and the ramping up of offensive operations on the part of the Machines.